# elementary OS freezes completely

Tags: system-installation, system

I recently installed elementary on an old computer core 2 duo 2.8 ghz 3gb ram. After a while it freezes completely, I can't access console `tty` so I have to do a hard reset. How can I find what causes that?

Comment: I had these problem with elementary Luna, now with Freya all it is fine. What OS are you using? Have you checked the output of the command `dmesg`?

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 suggestions and questions for you. We need to analyze the environment before we fix and come to conclusion.

1. After freeze, hard reboot your machine. After that open one console, do a sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog on it continue using your machine for a while and observe when it freezes what message is shown on console window.
2. By any chance do you have bad sectors on your old HDD?
3. We also need to check if your CPU is over heating. We can do that with hddtemp utility.

First post your reply and we will further debug it.